# App not registering in the "Share" menu as ACTION_SEND intent handler

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I have a free and paid Android app both based on the same core library code with just different subpackage names, a simple full version boolean switch and "LITE" in the app name for the free one. It is designed to receive image files and process them. The AndroidManifest.xml file is setup as:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
        </intent-filter>
```

On all the emulators and devices I've tested both apps appear in the Share menu of the Gallery app fine but I have a user reporting he can only see the LITE version in the Share menu. The device is running 2.3. Supposedly the full version appeared once but hasn't reared its head since. He doesn't have this problem on another device running the same version of Android.

Has anyone heard of or know of similar phenomenon happening and/or the reason behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna answer my own question...

Basically this turned out to be a non-issue. The reason why the app wasn't showing in the Share menu was the "files" being selected to Share were not local images saved on the device but images in the Gallery put there by Picassa (and thus really stored on Google's servers so not available via the normal ACTION_SEND intent).

Answer (score 1):

Basically this turned out to be a non-issue. The reason why the app wasn't showing in the Share menu was the "files" being selected to Share were not local images saved on the device but images in the Gallery put there by Picassa (and thus really stored on Google's servers so not available via the normal `ACTION_SEND` intent).

Answer (score 0):

You should add android:scheme="file" to your data - this way your app will be triggered only on sharing local files and not URLs (remote ones).

Comment: This will not work, because the SEND action does not filter the scheme, because it does not use the URI.

Answer (score 0):

Set `exported="true"` in manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name="....."
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```