# Application not appearing in share via list of android

Tags: java, android

Am trying to make my application to respond to action when user perform share via on any type of file in android, particularly audio and images for that i have added following code into my manifiest declaration of responding activity.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />

    </activity>
```

But even after doing show, my app is nowhere in the choose list, any clue any one where am going wrong?

Comment: did you expand the list? mine appeared in the "more..." section

Comment: I explored the list fully, but didnt saw my app in list :(

Comment: you need to put that in an `intent-filter`

Comment: my bad, what a stupid mistake :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its was a silly mistake, thanks for njZk2 for pointing out, I missed to declare those lines inside Intent-filter tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <intent-filter android:label="Share with my app" >
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> <== you are missing this

     <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
   </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Let me thy this missing category.

Comment: no luck, its still the same, my app is not featuring in the list, by the way that particular missing category is for handling web related url's.

Comment: did you try uninstalling and reinstalling app afterwards? there may be a cached android manifest file that needs to be replaced

Comment: Yep did all shorts of things, but still not able to understand whats the issue !!

Comment: are you using star/star as mime type?

Comment: yes, i tried all sorts of combinations e.g audio/* video/* */* but still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

The image/file your trying to share is on the google cloud rather than on your device due to which its failing.

Kindly verify the same it seems to be a repeat. See

[App not registering in the "Share" menu as ACTION_SEND intent handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951182/app-not-registering-in-the-share-menu-as-action-send-intent-handler)

Comment: No, i was trying to share files via file explorer, it is well on my device.

Comment: I have updated entire snap of my activity declaration.